# Table Reference Formula Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm using a formula to lookup-up values from a table in excel. The formula is added to a cell via VBA.

The formula is in use on two sheets, looking up the same information from a table on a third sheet.

In it's entered form the formula is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(PSE_Data[#All],MATCH($F7,'PSE Data'!K:K,0),16),"")
```

When I record adding this formula through VBA on one sheet it is recorded as:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(PSE_Data[#All],MATCH(RC6,'PSE Data'!C[-12],0),16),"""")
```

on the other sheet it is recorded as:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(PSE_Data[#All],MATCH(RC6,'PSE Data'!C[-2],0),16),"""")
```

I understand that the C[-2] and C[-12] must be some sort of referencing for the column within the table, but what I don't understand is why that reference would be different when using the formula in separate sheets. Could someone explain or point me in the right direction of some resources?

Comment: Research R1C1 referencing. Note - you can enter the formula in VBA in its A1 referencing form (i.e. using `K:K`)

Comment: or use the absolute R1C1 Reference `C11`  Note the missing brackets.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen a quick google and that explains it. I'd heard of structured references but had never seen this before!